# solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory does not work with AND clause

Tags: solr

I have a field

```
    <fieldType name="text_path" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/" replace="/"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

And two queries:

```
content:* AND {!parent which='-_nest_path_:* *:*'}+fullPath:"test/Test Test/Contract"

{!parent which='-_nest_path_:* *:*'}+fullPath:"test/Test Test/Contract"
```

It works with second query, but first raises error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 31.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\"test/Test Test/Contract"
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Usually localparams should be the first thing in the query - try moving it first and having the AND afterwards; in addition, `field:*` might need to be replaced with `field:[* TO *]` if you want to get everything with a value in the field. I think your issue is related to the parent filter and not the keyword tokenizer by itself, but the full stacktrace should be able to say more.

Comment: @MatsLindh moving AND afterwards partly helped - no error but no results though ( but definitely I should get it)